# redirect to paypal payment

Tags: php, http

Evening all. What I am wanting to do is after a user has clicked on a 'buynow' button for paypal, firstly go to a page that stores the items the have bought in a db and then redirect to the paypal payment.

This is what i have:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['cmd']) && isset($_POST['hosted_button_id']) && isset($_POST['diskSpace']) && isset($_POST['bandwidth']) && isset($_POST['subdomains']) && isset($_POST['additionalftp']) && isset($_POST['mysqldatabases']) && isset($_POST['emailforwarding']) && isset($_POST['autoresponders']) && isset($_POST['emaildistribution']) && isset($_POST['mailboxes']) && isset($_POST['oneclick']) && isset($_POST['operatingsystem'])){

    $cmd = $_POST['cmd'];
    $custom =  md5(date("his").microtime());
    $hosted_button_id = $_POST['hosted_button_id'];

    $diskSpace = $_POST['diskSpace'];
    $bandwidth = $_POST['bandwidth'];
    $subdomains = $_POST['subdomains'];
    $additionalftp = $_POST['additionalftp'];
    $mysqldatabases = $_POST['mysqldatabases'];
    $emailforwarding = $_POST['emailforwarding'];
    $autoresponders = $_POST['autoresponders'];
    $emaildistribution = $_POST['emaildistribution'];
    $mailboxes = $_POST['mailboxes'];
    $oneclick = $_POST['oneclick'];
    $operatingsystem = $_POST['operatingsystem'];

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
    $db = mysql_select_db('', $con);    

    if(!mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hostingAccounts` ORDER BY id")){
        $createTable = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hostingAccounts` (
        `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
        `ref` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `disk_space` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `bandwidth` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `sub_domains` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `additional_ftp` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `mysql_databases` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `email_forwarding` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `auto_responders` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `email_distribution` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `mailboxes` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `one_click_apps` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `operating_system` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `payer_email` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `first_name` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `last_name` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `payer_id` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `address_street` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `address_city` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `address_state` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `address_zip` TEXT NOT NULL, 
        `address_country` TEXT NOT NULL
        ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;");

        mysql_query($createTable);
    } 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hostingAccounts` (ref, disk_space, bandwidth, sub_domains, additional_ftp, mysql_databases, email_forwarding, auto_responders, email_distribution, mailboxes, one_click_apps,  operating_system) VALUES ('$custom', '$diskspace', '$bandwidth', '$subdomains', '$additionalftp', '$mysqldatabases', '$emailforwarding', '$autoresponders', '$emaildistribution', '$mailboxes', '$oneclick', '$operatingsystem')") or die (mysql_error());

    $host = "https://www.paypal.com";
    $path = "/cgi-bin/webscr";
    $data = "cmd=".$cmd."&hosted_button_id=".$hosted_button_id."&custom=".$custom;
    $data = urlencode($data);

    header("POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n" );
    header("Host: $host\r\n" );
    header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" );
    header("Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n" );
    header("Connection: close\r\n\r\n" );
    header($data);
}
?>
```

problem being it just comes up with "Internal Server Error". Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
- [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-PHP-Security-Chris-Snyder/dp/1590595084/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1263399530&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595084)

Edit:

> ```
> header("POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n" );
> ```

You might trying using the curl_* family of functions if you want to a POST within your script.

Also, you need to attempt to sanitize your client's input:

```
$cmd = $_POST['cmd'];
```

Also, why not just create the table yourself. Its a lot of needless overhead to be doing that select every request: (not to mention pretty wonky - you have your DB schema in your code ...)

```
if(!mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hostingAccounts` ORDER BY id")){
        $createTable = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hostingAccounts` (
        `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
```

Comment: Let's not discourage people from asking questions by mocking them, asking questions is one way we learn. Let's engage with them constructively. (And indeed, the OP needs to learn about the issues you've kindly provided links for.)

Comment: I need to add the data to the database for a few reasons. 1, once the payment is accepted I use the Paypal API to send and recieve the reference code to a script which then looks up the specification required for the hosting package bought and then uses another API to create that hosting package, activate and then send on the relevent information off to the client.

Comment: forgot to mention they are custom hosting packages not pre made.

Comment: And another, this is something i've just knocked up. I have not done much with http headers. I know all about -     * http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html
    * http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
    * http://www.amazon.com/Pro-PHP-Security-Chris-Snyder/dp/1590595084/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1263399530&sr=1-2

just trying to work out the posting method.

Answer (score 0):

[header()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) cannot do POST to another server.
Use [curl](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [Zend_Http](http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) or PEAR's [Http_Client](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Client)

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to tell me why this does not redirect?

```
$sendTo = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
$header[] = "Content-type: text/html";

$dataArray[] = "cmd=".$cmd;
$dataArray[] = "hosted_button_id=".$hosted_button_id;
$dataArray[] = "custom=".$custom;

$post = implode($dataArray, '&');
$post = urlencode($post);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

die();
```

Comment: Why are you calling "die();"...you won't give the script time to finish execution.

Comment: Still nothing. Does curl actualy redirect the user?